# VB.NET - Extracting text inside quotation in a complex string

Tags: vb.net, string, get, extract

I have a string looking like this:

```
a:391:i:0;s:12:"jnKKPkvpNnfn";i:1;s:12:"ic9VAk3PvQ3j";i:2;s:12:"PEBFuE6bGepr";i:3;s:12:"bwuxRkH6QbGp";i:4;s:12:"LSRDQbAKXc9q";i:5;s:12:"eLuVbSAxQCgo";}
```

And I want to get the text inside the quotations and send them to a listbox.
I know sort of how to do it, but in an ineffective way that might now work... So I'm asking for advice with an example on how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Post your attempt first and then people can offer suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Also you have to escape the quotes before doing anything: Dim input As String = """jnKKPkvpNnfn"";i:1;s:12:""ic9VAk3PvQ3j"";i:2;s:12:""PEBFuE6bGepr"";i:3;s:12:""bwuxRkH6QbGp"";i:4;s:12:""LSRDQbAKXc9q"";i:5;s:12:""eLuVbSAxQCgo"";}"

Comment: People is too impatient! I, personally, will not write mine until seeing yours :)

Comment: It's very difficult to say how best to to this without knowing more specifically what the specifications of the string format are.  For instance, what is the meaning of the colons and semicolons?  Do you just want a list of all the quoted strings, or do you only want them if the occur in a certain field/order/position?  Can quotations occur singly anywhere else (without a closing quote)?  Can quotes show up inside the quoted string?  If so, how are the escaped?  etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started; the method will run through an input string and return an array of strings that are contained within quotes.

```
    string[] ParseQuotes(string input)
    {
        List<string> matches = new List<string>();
        bool open = false;
        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == '"')
            {
                if (!open)
                {
                    open = true;
                    index = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    open = false;
                    string match = input.Substring(index + 1, index - i - 1);
                    matches.Add(match);
                }
            }
        }

        return matches.ToArray();
    }
```

Converted to VB...

```
Private Function ParseQuotes(input As String) As String()
    Dim matches As New List(Of String)()
    Dim open As Boolean = False
    Dim index As Integer = -1

    For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
        If input(i) = """"C Then
            If Not open Then
                open = True
                index = i
            Else
                open = False
                Dim match As String = input.Substring(index + 1, index - i - 1)
                matches.Add(match)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return matches.ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main code:

```
cbYourcomboBox.Items.Clear()
cbYourcomboBox.Items.AddRange(GetList(str).ToArray)
```

and then the function itself:

```
Public Function GetList(ByVal str As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim ar As String()
    Dim ar2 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    ar = Split(str, Chr(34))

    ' making sure there is a matching closing quote with - (UBound(ar) And 1)
    For a As Integer = 1 To UBound(ar) - (UBound(ar) And 1) Step 2
        ar2.Add(ar(a))
    Next a

    Return ar2
End Function
```